# stdarg.h not handling char pointer

Tags: c, pointers, char, arguments

So i have been trying to use stdarg for indefinite arguments. For int it works great but now i am trying this with char pointer. This is my code:

```
    void updateValue(char *parameter, parameterTypes type, ...)
    {
       va_list arg_list;
       U32 value;
       char* stringValue;

       va_start(arg_list, type);
       value = va_arg(arg_list, U32);
       stringValue = va_arg(arg_list, char*);
       va_end(arg_list);
       printf("\n\n%s\n\n", stringValue);
    }
```

when i call this function i simply use:

```
    updateValue("name", stringType, "TestingVaArg");
```

The first two parameters are for the name of the parameter in the list and the type of it. This works without the stdarg setup so this is not the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're supposed to *use* the `type` argument to figure out the type of the variable part. You seem to be accessing *both* a `U32` and a `char*`, when only passing a single argument.

You need something like:

```
if( type == stringType )
{
  char *stringValue = va_arg(arg_list, char *);
  print("got string '%s'\n", stringValue);
}
else if( type == u32Type )
{
 /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With these two lines

```
value = va_arg(arg_list, U32);
stringValue = va_arg(arg_list, char*);
```

you try to get *two* values from the stack, but you only pass *one* argument for the va-list. This means that when you try to get the string you will go outside the parameter list on the stack, and get a seemingly random pointer.

Comment: hmm I changed it and indeed it works but doesn't this make this whole library pointless? so I can't use this when I want to pass an int or a char*?

Comment: @flexzican The `va_arg` "function" _modifies_ the `arg_list` to point to the next argument when you call it. Each time you call `va_arg` you get the next argument, and it uses the type to decide how much to modify `arg_list`.